# Make redirect necessary to view a url

Tags: django, authentication

I have one URL "mywebsite/home" where I have a login form. I'm redirecting the user upon login to another URL "mywebsite/users". I have the login credentials in my database and it is supposed to be used by only limited people. So how can I make the redirect compulsory for viewing "mywebsite/users"? I'm using django, right now anyone who knows the URL can access the page.

my views is as follows:

```
 def home(request):
   usr = request.GET.get('username')
   pas = request.GET.get('password')
   userdata = Login.objects.filter(Q(username = usr) | Q(userid = usr))
   if Login.objects.filter(Q(username = usr) | Q(userid = usr)).exists():
     p = list(userdata.values('password'))
     b = p[0]['password']
        if pas == b:
            request.session['usr'] = usr
            return redirect('/users')

def users(request):
    return render(request, "ex.html")
```

Comment: Oh dear. I do hope you are not writing your own login mechanism that is storing passwords as plain text. You must **not ever ever do this**. Use Django's [authentication framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/).

Comment: Which, incidentally, has a `@login_required` decorator which is a lot more sensible than relying on redirects.

Comment: yeah, i was trying that, i have google login in my homepage though for which I dont have a database

Comment: What? You've got a Login object there, which is quite clearly a Django model which is stored in a database. Just don't do that; use the provided User model.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using google login you may not be able to use `@login_required` decorator.As per the view defined above you are adding a key `'usr'` in session which i assume can be used to check if the user has a valid login. Then you can use this custom decorator:

```
def user_login(function):
    ''' User login decorator'''
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kw):
        ''' wrapper '''
        if 'usr' not in request.session:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
        else:
            return function(request, *args, **kw)
    return wrapper
```

and use it as

```
@user_login
def users(request):
    return render(request, "ex.html")
```

Make sure that you remove the key from session when the user logout